# Finding the sum of an Infinite series involving logs to the base 2

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was trying to get into the habit of spending 30 minutes solving mathematical questions each day after reading an article from Keith McNulty on medium.

(https://keith-mcnulty.medium.com/start-your-day-with-math-268f75bd9289)

I was attempting the following question:

> Find the sum of the infinite series

> $$  log_{2} e - log_{4} e + log_{8} e - ... + (-1)^nlog_{2^{2^{n}}} e + .... $$

My Work:

So we can get each term in our series to be in the following form using the "Change of Base formula"

$$log_{2} e =   \frac{ln(e)}{ln (2)}
=\frac{1}{ln (2)}$$

This leads to the following:

$$S  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{n}ln (2)}$$ $$ =\frac{1}{ln (2)}  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{n}}$$

With the summation part being an alternating harmonic series, we would get

$$S  = \frac{1}{ln (2)} * ln (2) = 1 $$

The question however stated that the answer should be:
$$S = \frac{1}{ln (2\sqrt{2})} $$

Have I arrived at the right answer?

Comment: Check again, your summation (after your simplifications) isn't the alternating harmonic series, it's a G.P.

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out. So would the answer be 2/(3ln(2))?

Comment: Yes.  Which is the same as the answer stated in the question.  Of course things would have been a lot faster if you had recognised the original series $(-1)^n\log_{2^{2^n}}e$ as a G.P.!